# Include packages doesn't seem to exist on composer-php install

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer-php

I have installed two packages with composer on unbuntu 16:

- phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
- setasign/fpdi-tcpdf:2.1

both have installed ok, here is the output from phpoffice.

```
Using version ^1.5 for phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 3 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
- Installing markbaker/complex (1.4.7): Downloading (100%)
- Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.1): Downloading (100%)
- Installing phpoffice/phpspreadsheet (1.5.2): Downloading (100%)
phpoffice/phpspreadsheet suggests installing mpdf/mpdf (Option for rendering PDF                                                                                 with PDF Writer)
phpoffice/phpspreadsheet suggests installing dompdf/dompdf (Option for rendering                                                                                       PDF with PDF Writer)
phpoffice/phpspreadsheet suggests installing jpgraph/jpgraph (Option for renderi                                                                                      ng charts, or including charts with PDF or HTML Writers)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

for both of these i have used the basic example on their home page, For example, the phpoffice one (https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/)

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('hello world.xlsx');
```

When running this i get the following on the apache error log (i get a similar one when running the fpdi-tcpdf.)

```
[Thu Dec 06 21:14:42.835498 2018] [:error] [pid 1582] [client 192.168.223.1:53200] PHP Warning:  require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/custom/excel.php on line 3
[Thu Dec 06 21:14:42.835716 2018] [:error] [pid 1582] [client 192.168.223.1:53200] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/custom/excel.php on line 3
```

Comment: You're getting this error because PHP can't find `vendor/autoload.php` in your current folder (according to error message, it should be `/var/www/html/custom/vendor/autoload.php`). I would recommend to check the full path to your composer `vendor` folder

Answer (score 0):

thanks Krlv

I found the vendor folder using this command:

```
composer config --list --global
```

then replaced

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

with the full path of autoload.php and it has worked.